# mapply changes dates to double

Tags: r, mapply

how can I prevent mapply from changing dates to doubles?

This is what I mean:

```
datedf<-data.frame(y=as.character(rep(2010,12)),m=as.character(seq(1,12,1)),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
head(datedf)

yyyymm_to_date<-function(y,m) {
  return(as.Date(paste0(y,ifelse(nchar(m)==1,paste0("0",m),m),"01"),"%Y%m%d"))
}    

yyyymm_to_date("2000","4") # prints "2010-04-01"

datedf$d<-mapply(FUN=yyyymm_to_date,y=datedf$y,m=datedf$m,SIMPLIFY=FALSE) # simplify does not help
head(datedf) # prints double numbers ?? --> want dates
```

Thx&kind regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need a `do.call` (since `mapply` returns a `list`), your code is perfectly fine:

```
datedf$d <- do.call('c',mapply(FUN=yyyymm_to_date,y=datedf$y,m=datedf$m,SIMPLIFY=FALSE))
head(datedf)
#     y m          d
#1 2010 1 2010-01-01
#2 2010 2 2010-02-01
#3 2010 3 2010-03-01
#4 2010 4 2010-04-01
#5 2010 5 2010-05-01
#6 2010 6 2010-06-01
```

Answer (score 2):

A one-liner instead of all this function calls.

```
as.Date(with(datedf, paste(y, sprintf("%02d", as.numeric(m)), "01", sep = "-")))

# "2010-01-01" "2010-02-01" "2010-03-01" "2010-04-01" "2010-05-01" 
# "2010-06-01" "2010-07-01" "2010-08-01" "2010-09-01" "2010-10-01" 
# "2010-11-01" "2010-12-01"
```

Checking the class

```
a <- as.Date(with(datedf, paste(y,sprintf("%02d", as.numeric(m)),"01",sep = "-"))))
class(a)
#[1] "Date"
```

We `paste` `01` to every combination of Year (`y`) and Month (`m`) and then convert it to Date by `as.Date`.